# How can I find duplicate values in the column of a table I am trying to index?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FreqLeeds] (
    [Id]   INT             NOT NULL,
    [Freq] DECIMAL (18, 5) NOT NULL,
    [Text] NVARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

After populating the table I tried to create an index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_FreqLeeds_Text] ON [dbo].[FreqLeeds] ([Text])
```

But the `create` failed because of a duplicate value.

How can I determine which rows have duplicates and what the value is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the text which are present more than once using aggregation:

```
select [Text]
from [dbo].[FreqLeeds]
group by [Text]
having count(*) > 1
```

If you want to see all the rows (with all the columns) for the text that are present more than once, you can use window function `count` in subquery (or CTE) and filter:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        count(*) over (partition by [Text]) cnt
    from [dbo].[FreqLeeds] t
) t where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks.  This worked well.  Now I have to actually find out a way to remove these.  Might open up a different question for that.

Comment: Or you can try something yourself first (such as study some SQL, or write a naive program in another language), why do you expect that all work will be done for you?

Answer (score 1):

you can try to query your table in this way

```
Select count(*), [Text]
from [dbo].[FreqLeeds]
group by [Text]
having count(*) > 1
```